# Auth0 upgrade to Node8

Tags: java, node.js, npm, auth0

My applications are on Node-v4 and use Auth0 for authorisation. End of May, Auth0 is being upgraded to Node-v8 stopping support for Node-v4. Should I also be updating my applications to a higher level of Node or will the applications work fine as is even after Auth0 updated? Please let me know

**What I Tried:** I've upgraded my applications to Node-v8 and v10 and did not see any code changes to be performed but, updating production to a higher level raises questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your** **applications** should not be effected by Auth0's upgrade to node 8.

**The Auth0 extensibility tools** are the ones being moved to node8. If you use rules, hooks, etc. you will need to be concious of that move, but not with your local apps.

There is handy a migration guide that provides a good amount of insight in this area.

https://auth0.com/docs/migrations/guides/extensibility-node8

With that being said, Node 4 is end-of-life as of April 30th. However that effects you and your applications could be different.

https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule

Comment: Thanks, @dan-woda, I've also got the same response from Auth0 team and I can confirm the applications would not break after the Auth0 upgrade to Node8 but, are at risk as they are not supported anymore. Cheers

Comment: No problem! I am a member of the community team at Auth0, as noted in my profile. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

`Should I also be updating my applications to a higher level of Node or will the applications work fine as is even after Auth0 updated ?` Auth0 will not update your node version. You have to update yourself.

Comment: The question is not if Auth0 upgrades my applications, will my applications (on Node4) be fine even after Auth0 updates its API to Node8